# Having a problem doing linear interpolation with multiple 0.0 values in a row in python

Tags: python, loops, linear-interpolation

In this problem I am trying to linearly interpoplate a set of provided data without numpy or any other importable functions. The problem really arises when I am trying to linearly interpolate between values when there is more than one 0.0 value (i.e 4.0, 0.0, 0.0, 3.0 should result in 4.0, 3.6, 3.3, 3.0) but I get errors. I think this may have to do with the way I re-add the interpolated values to the list or it could have to do with interpolation itself.

This is what I have so far:

```
RandC = input('input r and c')
rdata = input('enter data')
k = rdata.split()
a = 0
jay = []
for i in k:
    jay.append([a,float(i)])
    a += 1
newvals = []

x1 = 0.0
x2 = 0.0
for i in jay:
    x = i[1]
    y = i[0]
    if x != 0.0 and x1 == 0.0:
        x1 = x
        y1 = y
    elif x == 0.0:
        ya = y
    elif x != 0.0:
        x2 = x
        y2 = y
    if x1 != 0.0 and x2 != 0.0:
        ans = (x1 + (((ya - y1)*(x2-x1))/(y2 - y1)))
        newvals.append(ans)
        x1 = x2
        y1 = y2
        x2 = 0.0
        y2 = 0.0
for i in jay:
    if i[1] == 0.0:
        i[1] = newvals[0]
        newvals.pop(0)
        
        
mylist = []        
print(RandC)
for i in jay:
    mylist.append(i[1])
print(*mylist)
```

Here is also a test bit of data I'm trying to make work:

1.0 0.0 0.0 2.0 0.0 0.0 3.0 0.0 0.0 4.0 0.0 0.0 5.0

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind. After some head-scratching, I came up with a kinda janky method. I'll post it below.

[updated code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Ku9B.png)